# QuestaSim .desktop closes after a short time

Tags: command-line

I have created a  `.desktop` file for an application I have installed. This is the code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=QuestaSim
Comment=QuestaSim
Icon=/usr/share/icons/QuestaSim.png
Path=/storage/questa/v10.7c/questasim/linux_x86_64
Exec=vsim
Terminal=false
```

However, when I double-click this file, the program opens but closes after without showing me the program itself, I just check whether it is opening or not from `System Monitor`. However, when I run `vsim` from the terminal, it runs perfectly. Also, when I change the last line of me `.desktop` file to `Terminal=true` it also runs perfectly with starting a terminal.

When I run the program by just writing `vsim` to the terminal or double-clicking the working `.desktop` file, this is the output on the terminal:

`Reading pref.tcl`

However, when I run the program from the not working `.desktop` file by writing `gtk-launch <filename>.desktop`, the output is:

```
Reading pref.tcl

# 10.7c

# 
# <EOF>
```

and it does not terminate. What can be the reason, and what is your suggestion for the solution? Thanks.

Edit1: This is the screen that I want to see. When I run vsim from command line, it works fine. You can see the graphical interface, the output at terminal, and system monitor.
[image]

However, when I run it from the .desktop file I use, the output at terminal is different as you can see, and the `vish` process terminates after just a second. The programs graphical interface also does not show up.
[image]

Comment: What is wrong with setting `Terminal=true`?

Comment: @vanadium nothing is wrong. However, I do not want a new terminal to be opened, for other applications I can run them with ```Terminal=false```.

Comment: Also, another application will run this program from a .sh. However, it shows the same behavior. This program first opens but closes after just a couple of seconds.

Comment: OF course, it is difficult for us to imagine what you see and what is going on. You may want to provide a more specific description on the application, what you expect to see and what you actually see. Is it a graphical program, and not one, such as htop, that is supposed to run in a terminal? An another level, is there actually advantage of having this particular software start through a launcher?

Comment: @vanadium I have edited my post. Thanks

Comment: The contents of the .desktop file in your screenshot is different than that included in your post?

Comment: @vanadium I am trying all variations.

Comment: What do you mean by "working .desktop file" in contrast to "the not working .desktop file"? Is't it then just matter of using the working one?

Comment: @vanadium Working means, it opens the graphical interface of the program as intended but also terminal, ```Terminal=true```. The not working means, the graphical interface does not show up,  ```Terminal=false```.

Comment: Probably the program starts from a terminal and then loads the graphical assets from there in the background.